# Player sprite not showing up in game view

Tags: unity

I'm new to game development in Unity, and I can't figure out why my player doesn't appear in-game but everything else does.

[image]

This is what it looks like when running it. It's still there but it's gone:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you run the game, can you select your player in the hierachy and check the Transform of it? It might fall through the floor or just hidden behind something

Comment: You see `missing sprite` on your player/ sprite renderer. Since the sprite is not set (or changed by code) to something that does not exist, please include the code that changes the sprite on your player (since it is shown in the editor, something else breaks it later)

Comment: alright ill try thanks!